# For every integer vector $\overrightarrow{a}$,there is a integer vector $\overrightarrow{b}$ such that $\overrightarrow{a}\bot\overrightarrow{b}$

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, contest-math

In $R^3$,show that for every integer vector $\overrightarrow{a}$,there is a integer vector $\overrightarrow{b}$ such that  $\overrightarrow{a}\bot\overrightarrow{b}$

Generally,in $R^n$,for every vector $\overrightarrow{a}$, it is right,too?

Comment: I assume, that the $0$-vector is not allowed, otherwise the result would be trivial.

Comment: Just for be clear, an integer vector is a vector with integer components?

Answer (score 5):

If $\overrightarrow{a}=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$,and $a_1,a_2$ are not both zero, then take $\overrightarrow{b}=(-a_2,a_1,0)$. If $a_1=a_2=0$, take $(1,0,0)$.

I will leave it to you to figure out why this works.

Answer (score 4):

Assume, $a\ne 0$ because the orthogonality does not make sense for $a=0$.

It is true for every $n$. Choose some two components of the vector a, of
which one is not $0$. Swap them and change one of the signs. Set the other
entries $0$. Then, you have found a vector $b$ orthogonal to $a$ with integer coefficients.

Comment: Is this really a question of a math-contest ?

Answer (score 3):

For $a =[a_1 , a_2 ,...,a_n ]$ take $b=[a_n ,a_n,...,a_n, -(a_1 +a_1 +...+a_{n-1} )].$

Answer (score 0):

Another answer (on top of all the already existing excellent one).

Suppose $a\neq (1,0,0....)$ (called $i$)

Then $a \times i$ is integer and orthogonal to $a$.

If $a=i$, take $j$

Comment: What's with all the periods?

Comment: @CameronBuie The OP was also talking about $\mathbb{R}^n$, so I wrote the answer accordingly, it works with any $n$

Comment: Fair enough. How would you define cross product in $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: In fact there are extension of cross product for any $n$. The only one that is close to $R^3$ is for $n=$. Otherwise you have to do the cross product of $(n-1)$ vectors as a multilinear alternate application. It does not have all the same caracteristics as for $n=3$ (Jacobi for instance) but the orthogonality holds.